# Combine Bar and Line subplots in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 5 time series that I want to graph in a subplot. Essentially I've been using subplotting:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, figsize=(16,10), sharex=True)
xlim = (start, end)
ax1=df.hr.plot(ax=axes[0], color='green', xlim=xlim)
ax2=df.act.plot(ax=axes[1], color='orange', xlim=xlim)
ax3=df.rr.plot(ax=axes[2], color='blue', xlim=xlim)
ax4=df2.set_index('timestamp').rmssd.plot(color='purple', ax=axes[3], xlim=xlim)
ax5=ma_df.tz_convert('US/Eastern')['any_act'].resample('10Min', how='count').plot(kind='line',ax=axes[4])
```

Which produces

[image]

Due to the nature of the data, I want to visualize the last subplot as bar chart. So naturally, I changed the last line to:

```
ax5=ma_df.tz_convert('US/Eastern')['any_act'].resample('10Min', how='count').plot(kind='bar',ax=axes[4])
```

Which then creates the following figure:

[image]

Which, produces what I expect in the last subplot, but makes the other plots useless. Needless to say, it's not what I want.

How can I combine the 4 line time series with one bar chart in the same plot, but different subplots, all sharing the same x-axis?
Meaning I would want the first 4 subplotplots like in the first image, and the last subplot like in the second image.

**Update**

I made a simple example, which unfortunately works as expected, and does not replicate my problem, which is even more baffling. Code is below

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df =  pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/temp-leonsas-qsaeamu0sl5v4b/df.csv')
bar_df = pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/temp-leonsas-qsaeamu0sl5v4b/bar_df.csv')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, figsize=(16,10), sharex=True)
ax1=df.hr.plot(ax=axes[0], color='green', kind='line')
ax2=df.act.plot(ax=axes[1], color='orange', kind='line')
ax3=df.rr.plot(ax=axes[2], color='blue', kind='line')
ax4=bar_df.occ_count.plot(ax=axes[3], kind='bar')
```

Whereas the code in my codebase which replicates the problem is

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, figsize=(16,10), sharex=True)
ax1=df.hr.plot(ax=axes[0], color='green', kind='line')
ax2=df.act.plot(ax=axes[1], color='orange', kind='line')
ax3=df.rr.plot(ax=axes[2], color='blue', kind='line')
ax4=bar_df.occ_count.plot(ax=axes[3], kind='bar')
```

The main difference is that in my codebase the DataFrames are being generated and not just loaded up from s3. Is there an implicit config inside a DataFrame that can somehow make this happen? I just used `df.to_csv` to dump those 2 dataframes into S3.

Comment: Have you tried calling the barplot first, and the line plots afterwards? You are probably getting unwanted helper activity from the resample, but this is not a complete example. At least give dummy data and see how many of the line plots you need to reproduce the error. [MVCE]

Comment: @cphlewis see my update on post.

Comment: it could be that the indexes are subtly different, try calling `reset_index` on your dataframes before plotting

Comment: If maxymoo's suggestion doesn't work, you can narrow in on how much of the data is needed to reproduce this. The first half? The second half? The fist half of the second half? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to explicitly pass `kind='line'` to the first three plots, here's a simpler example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,2,1])
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(16,10), sharex=True)
s.plot(ax=axes[0], color='green', kind='line')
s.plot(ax=axes[1], color='red', kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. Maybe it's related to the resampling? See how in my 2 figures, the axis tick labels are vary different in quantity.

Comment: hmm dunno ... can you add some data into your question to make it reproducible?